# savepoint commit rollback in mysql

Tags: mysql

how can we use commit, rollback and savepoint in mysql ?

Answer (score 17):

```
CREATE TABLE t_test (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB;

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT
INTO    t_test
VALUES  (1);

SELECT  *
FROM    t_test;

 id
---
  1

SAVEPOINT tran2;

INSERT
INTO    t_test
VALUES  (2);

SELECT  *
FROM    t_test;

 id
---
  1
  2

ROLLBACK TO tran2;

SELECT  *
FROM    t_test;

 id
---
  1

ROLLBACK;

SELECT  *
FROM    t_test;

 id
---
```

Comment: Can I run these as Queries in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 8):

```
mysql> start transaction;
mysql> savepoint id;
```

Here you alter the table data and then:

```
mysql> rollback to savepoint id;
```

View the data and finally:

```
mysql> release savepoint id;
```